# Spring boot jpa - how are the entities updated in the DB?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm performing simple update operations, but I can't figure out what is the logic behind the update. I'm asking this before I've tested the operations with different entities, and some of them, after been updated, were added at the bottom of the table in the DB, while some others in the middle between other non-updated entities.
 I'm using postgres and using pgAdmin to check my rows. The primary key stays the same for all the entities I'm updating, but they are shifted in a way that appears random to me.
Someone can help me figure out what's the logic?
If could be of any use, this is my db:

[image]

In this case, the entities with all the values (except for the id) equals to 6 were the one updated and shifted in this position. Other ones are at the bottom or in other positions:

[image]

Comment: I have to say you got me completely lost. Are you asking for the logic your database introspection tool uses to sort rows?

Comment: @crizzis I'm trying to understand why the rows are changed in position after updating, and which logic is followed.

Comment: What I fail to understand is what is it that you refer to as 'row position'